# 2-Way-TLS support

Tags: perl, ssl, soap

Server application is using following code to get the request from client to process. Now I got a requirement to make this call secure using HTTPS (2-way-tls). I need to convert this call to secure call in Perl and implement client authentication for trusted client. I am not sure how can I do that and how to provide certificates.

```
my $daemonname = "SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon";

$daemon = $daemonname

    ->new(Scheme => 'http', LocalPort => 8080, Listen => 128)
    ->dispatch_to('MyCode')
    ->options({compress_threshold => 10000});

$daemon->handle;
```

Comment: You can pass any arguments accepted by IO::Socket::SSL, incl `SSL_ca_path` and `SSL_ca_file`. This would provide a means of authentication. Using any option of the form `SLL_*` switches to HTTPS.

Comment: Also include the option `SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_PEER`. See [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) for all the options and their meaning.

Comment: So what would be the replacement of "->dispatch_to('MyCode')" and compression also?